# How to inject third party dependencies into Directive controllers in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive controller as follows.

```
 app.directive("dashboardApp", function(toastr){
 return {
     controller: function($scope, $rootScope){

     }
  }
```

I also have an XHR interceptor 'angular-loading-bar' that is added as a dependency to 'app'

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate'])
```

. But the interceptor isn't working in the dashboardApp controller. How do i inject this dependency into the directive controller.

Answer (score 0):

> It works automatically, so simply include it as a dependency and it
>   will automatically display the progress of your $http requests.

Injecting the module into your application should do the trick. No need in injecting it into your controller.

*Requirements: AngularJS 1.2+*

**Please check your installation, and re-check following steps**

**Include dependency**

include the loading bar as a dependency for your app. If you want animations, include `ngAnimate` as well. note: `ngAnimate` is optional. [Installation options here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate).

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate'])
```

**Include source files (via one of the following methods)**

**include the supplied JS and CSS file (or create your own CSS to override defaults).**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='build/loading-bar.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='build/loading-bar.min.js'></script>
That's it -- you're done!
```

**via bower:**

```
$ bower install angular-loading-bar
```

**via npm:**

```
$ npm install angular-loading-bar
```

**via CDN:**

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
 <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.js'></scrip
```